# How to add a relationship to the parent with Mantle?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, github-mantle

I have Parent/child class like this:

```
@interface Parent : MTLModel <MTLJSONSerializing>
- (void)someMethod;

@property a,b,c...;   // from the JSON    
@property NSArray *childs;  // from the JSON
@end

@interface Child : MTLModel <MTLJSONSerializing>
@property d,e,f,...;    // from the JSON    
@property Parent *parent;   // *not* in the JSON
@end
```

All the fields a to f are in the JSON, with the same name (hence my JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey method return nil), and the proper JSONTransformer is correctly setup so that the childs array in parent is containing Child class and not NSDictionary.

Everything work *forwardly*.

But I want, as a convenience, a property in my Child model that reference *back* to the parent that own it. So that in the code I can do that:

```
[childInstance.parent someMethod]
```

How do I do that with Mantle ??

I want, when the parent is parsing the child's JSON and creating the Child class, to add a ref to itself. (With an init method ??)

Thanks.

Comment: You will have to do that manually.

Answer (score 2):

I do this by overriding `MTLModel -initWithDictionary:error:` method. Something like this.

Child interface:

```
@interface BRPerson : MTLModel <MTLJSONSerializing>
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) BRGroup *group; // parent
@end
```

In parent implementation:

```
- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionaryValue error:(NSError **)error {
    self = [super initWithDictionary:dictionaryValue error:error];
    if (self == nil) return nil;

    // iterates through each child and set its parent
    for (BRPerson *person in self.people) {
        person.group = self;
    }
    return self;
}
```

**Techinical note:**

If you are curious like me, I already tried to tweak `MTLJSONAdapter` by changing its `forwardBlock` and `reversibleBlock`. But I can't, because those are inside `MTLReversibleValueTransformer` superclass, and that class is declared privately in **"MTLValueTransformer.m"**. So the `initWithDictionary` approach above should be much easier.